# Using different JSON configuration files in AUTOFAC for the same interface

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using Autofac JSON files to register two classes for the same interface in my project.

If I do something like this:

**JSON Config file 1:**

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Services.FirstProvider, Services",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "Services.IHotelProvider, Services"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "username": "<user>",
        "password": "<pwd>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSON Config file 2:**

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Services.SecondProvider, Services",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "Services.IHotelProvider, Services"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "key": "<key>",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**And register:**

```
config.AddJsonFile("First/FirstProviderConfig.json");
config.AddJsonFile("Second/SecondProviderConfig.json");
```

I can see that only the `SecondProvider`has been registered. And switching registration:

```
config.AddJsonFile("Second/SecondProviderConfig.json");
config.AddJsonFile("First/FirstProviderConfig.json");
```

Only `FirstProvider` has been registered.

If I try to register them in the same file:

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Services.FirstProvider, Services",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "Services.IHotelProvider, Services"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "username": "<user>",
        "password": "<pwd>"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Services.SecondProvider, Services",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "Services.IHotelProvider, Services"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "key": "<key>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It works.

I need to have separated files to configure them. What I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key point here is that you're using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration as the basis for configuration files now, which means configuration is somewhat governed by the way Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration behaves.

When you have configuration, the way Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration wants to handle it is to ***override* settings as you layer one configuration provider on top of another**.

In the simple case, say you have two configurations:

```
{
  "my-key": "a"
}
```

and

```
{
  "my-key": "b"
}
```

It doesn't create an array of all possible values; it'll layer the second over the first based on the key (`my-key`) matching and override to have the value `b`.

When you parse JSON configuration it flattens everything out into key/value pairs. Does the same with XML. It does this because configuration supports environment variables and INI files and all sorts of other backing stores.

In the case of the above very simple files, you get

```
my-key == b
```

Nice and flat. Looking at something more complex:

```
{
  "top": {
    "simple-item": "simple-value",
    "array-item": ["first", "second"]
  }
}
```

It flattens out like:

```
top:simple-item == simple-value
top:array-item:0 == first
top:array-item:1 == second
```

Notice how the array (an "ordinal collection") gets flattened? Each item gets auto-assigned a fake "key" that has a 0-based index.

Now think about how two config files will layer. If I have the above more complex configuration and then put this...

```
{
  "top": {
    "array-item": ["third"]
  }
}
```

That one flattens out to

```
top:array-item:0 == third
```

See where I'm going here? You layer that override config over the first one and you get:

```
top:simple-item == simple-value
top:array-item:0 == third
top:array-item:1 == second
```

The arrays don't *combine*, the key/value settings *override*.

**You see them in a JSON representation, but it's all just key/value pairs.**

You have two choices to try and fix this.

**Option 1: Fudge the Array (Not Recommended)**

Since your first configuration is (simplified):

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Services.FirstProvider, Services",
      "services": [ ...]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can potentially "fudge it" a little by putting a dummy empty element in the second "override" config:

```
{
  "components": [
    {
    },
    {
      "type": "Services.SecondProvider, Services",
      "services": [ ...]
    }
  ]
}
```

Last I checked, the override thing was additive-only, so empty values don't *erase* previously set values. By shifting the array in the second configuration by 1, it'll change the flattened version of the key/value representation and the two arrays should "merge" the way you want.

*But that's pretty ugly and I wouldn't do that.* I just wanted to show you one way to make it work so you'd understand why what you're doing isn't working.

**Option 2: Two Separate Configuration Modules (Recommended)**

Instead of trying to combine the two JSON files, just create two separate `IConfiguration` objects by individually loading the JSON files. Register them separately in two different `ConfigurationModule` registrations. It shouldn't blow up if either of the configurations is empty.

```
var first = new ConfigurationBuilder();
first.AddJsonFile("autofac.json", optional: true);
var firstModule = new ConfigurationModule(first.Build());
var second = new ConfigurationBuilder();
second.AddJsonFile("autofac-overrides.json", optional: true);
var secondModule = new ConfigurationModule(second.Build());
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(firstModule);
builder.RegisterModule(secondModule);
```

If the config is empty or missing it just won't register anything. If it's there, it will. In the case where you want to override things or add to your set of handlers for nice `IEnumerable<T>` resolution, this should work.

Comment: Is there an easy way to override one part of first json with the second? (granted that the keys match)

Comment: Oh my goodness.  THANK YOU.  This is also the case if you want to have a separate json file for DIFFERENT "family/grouping" of di items.   for example.   di.Animals.json, di.Cars.json, di.Colors.json.    Your "option 2" helped me use different json files for multiple files..where one file is a "grouping" of DependencyInjection needs.  The "overwriting" (as the question shows) was driving me nuts.  I'd give you 2 upvotes if I could.

Comment: And I agree, do not do Option1.  Option 2 is "clean"   :)